# Is it possible to purchase Ethereum with USD command line?

Tags: go-ethereum, exchanges, decentralized-exchange

I opened a wallet using [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) with this command

```
geth new account
```

Am I able to saturate this account by purchasing Ethereum with USD via the command-line? Are you usually charged a fee or can you find people who are just willing to sell?

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Do banks even have command-line for moving USD around? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean buying Ethereum for USD by interacting with the Ethereum blockchain, then you cannot do this because the Ethereum blockchain can only interact with tokens deployed on it.

So, if you have some stablecoin pegged to USD that belongs to your wallet address, such as DAI or USDC, you can use something like [web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) with Node to swap it on a DEX such as Uniswap via the command-line.

But the way Ethereum is traded for actual dollars is done on centralised exchanges such as Coinbase or Binance, where the centralised exchange keeps your secret keys for you and does not reveal them to you.

The usual steps for getting ETH onto an address that you directly control are:

1. Buying ETH through some centralised exchange.
2. Withdrawing this ETH from the centralised into an address you directly control.

Whether or not these steps can be done programmatically is outside your main question, but if you are interested in finding out more, then you ought to take a look at developer documentation for specific centralised exchanges.